# SQL Server stored procedure with geolocation not returning data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have written the following stored procedure to return data based on a lat/long and category id being passed.

I need to return a list of traders whose coverage area falls within the passed lat long (and that they cover the category being passed). So I am looking to draw a circle around the traders lat/long position, x number of meters using the radius they will operate from (this is stored in the `Traders.OperatingRadius` column). If the passed lat long coord is within this, then they should be included in the return list.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindTradersWithinRadiusLatLong 
    @LAT decimal(9,6),
    @LONG decimal(9,6),
    @CATEGORY int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @GEO1 GEOGRAPHY;

    SET @GEO1 = geography::Point(@LAT, @LONG, 4326)

    SELECT
        x.Id, x.Name, 
        x.Latitude, x.Longitude,
        x.Distance, x.IsArchived
    FROM
        (SELECT
             Traders.Id, Traders.Name,
             Latitude, Longitude,
             CategoryId = TraderCategories.Id,
             OperatingRadius,
             Traders.IsArchived,
             Distance = (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(Latitude, 0), ISNULL(Longitude, 0), 4326)))
         FROM
             ((Addresses
         INNER JOIN
             Traders ON Addresses.TraderId = Traders.Id)
         INNER JOIN
             TraderCategories ON Traders.Id = TraderCategories.TraderId)) AS x
    WHERE
        x.Distance <= x.OperatingRadius
        AND x.CategoryId = @CATEGORY
        AND (x.IsArchived = 0 OR x.IsArchived = NULL);
END
GO
```

`TraderCategories` is a linking table as follows;

```
    Table TraderCategories
    int FK TraderId 
    int FK CategoryId
```

Now I have added an address with;

```
latitiude - 43.590000, Longitude - -111.120000
```

There is also a TraderCategory Relationship for category with Id 1

I have then tried calling the stored procedure with the above and no matches are being returned.

The table definitions are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Bemfeito].[Addresses]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Address1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TraderId] [int] NULL,
    [Latitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
    [Longitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
    [OperatingRadius] [real] NOT NULL DEFAULT (CONVERT([real],(0)))

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Addresses] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Bemfeito].[Addresses]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Addresses_Traders_TraderId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([TraderId]) REFERENCES [Bemfeito].[Traders] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Bemfeito].[Addresses] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Addresses_Traders_TraderId]
GO

CREATE TABLE [Bemfeito].[Traders]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Traders] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Bemfeito].[TraderCategories]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] [int] NULL,
    [TraderId] [int] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TraderCategories] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [Bemfeito].[TraderCategories] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TraderCategories_Categories_CategoryId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [Bemfeito].[Categories] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Bemfeito].[TraderCategories] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TraderCategories_Categories_CategoryId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Bemfeito].[TraderCategories] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TraderCategories_Traders_TraderId] 
        FOREIGN KEY([TraderId]) REFERENCES [Bemfeito].[Traders] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Bemfeito].[TraderCategories] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TraderCategories_Traders_TraderId]
GO
```

and finally for completion the category

```
CREATE TABLE [Bemfeito].[Categories]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Value] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Categories] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
)
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong here please?

Comment: No comma after Traders.IsArchived in the subselect?

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo my end. It’s there in the stored procedure is added ok.

Comment: This query seems like it shouldn't work at all.  For Example you reference `IsArchived` column, but there is none.  (There is a IsArchived function on Traders where you pass distance?) I think you need to clean up that query.

Comment: you have no scale (default 0) or precision in your declaration of decimals. Therefore your latitude will round off to 44, and your longitude will round off to 111. I'd also action what @DanielGimenez said. The definition for IsAchived function may be useful also.

Comment: @DanielGimenez thanks for the response. the IsArchived field is a nullable bool on the Trader table. I've cleaned up the question text to reflect it, I am not sure what happend (maybe with the edit?)

Comment: @DimUser I have amended the question and also changed the default to be 0.000000, I am still getting no response though?

Comment: @MatthewFlynn - DimUser was pointing out that `@LAT decimal` is essentially `@LAT decimal(18,0)` - so it doesn't matter what decimals you're trying to pass in, none survive into the body of the stored procedure.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry, I see the point I have amended the SPROC to now use decimal(9,6) but its still not returning any data when I call it?

Comment: At this point we need some table definitions (simplified - remove columns not relevant to *this problem* such as `IsArchived`, `Name`, etc), sample data and expected results. If I try and mock up table definitions based on what you've posted and populate them and use your query, *I* get a result back. So you need to put more work into giving us an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at this microsoft reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2016) you should notice that the argument passed to STDistance is a geometry datatype while you are passing a Point datatype.

the line currently written like this

```
,Distance = (@geo1.STDistance(geography::Point(ISNULL(Latitude, 0), ISNULL(Longitude, 0), 4326))
```

should be written as follows.

```
,Distance = (@geo1.STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText('Point('+ISNULL(Longitude, 0)+' '+ISNULL(Latitude, 0)')',4326))
```

Comment: [`Point`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2016) returns a valid geography for `STDistance` to use. And if you're going to use the `POINT` WKT form, you have to remember that it takes longitude then latitude - so you've effectively swapped the coordinates here as well.

Comment: In what way is what gets returned by `Point()` not a an acceptable input for STDistance? Both your `STGeomFromText()` and it will return a geography instance that represents the point. In fact, I'd even go so far as to say that SQL Server would compare points created by the two methods as equal!

Comment: The Point definition may be a valid mechanism...but if he is trying to diagnose where the code is failing he can always use the definition form mentioned above inside his select to show exactly what is being past to the function.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank You for pointing out the incorrect Longitude/Latitude order in my Answer. I have corrected it. I wish Microsoft online documentation would include explicit argument definitions.